# IF, ELSE function gives wrong result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

my If else statelement is :

```
=IF(AC2<0,5;"0";IF(AC2<1,5;"1";IF(AC2<2,5;"2";"3")))
```

and AC is a column containing multiple values .

For example : AC2 value is : 2,27 the result should be 2 but i am getting 3 as a result and AC3 value is 0;83 and i get also 3 as result.

Conclusion : i am getting 3 as a result for all columns, it doesn't test all the IF but jumps directly into the ELSE statement.

Comment: Try `=MIN(ROUND(A2;0);3)`

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me.

Comment: Are you sure `,` is your decimal separator?

Comment: My guess is that your numbers are text that look like numbers and not true numbers.  Also remove the `"` around the numbers or you will continue the problem.

Comment: @zipa If the list separator is `;` (as seems to be the case in the above formula) then `,` is probably the correct decimal separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have inverted commas (`""`) which turns you're 1, 2 and 3 from numbers to text - as mentioned in the comments, there's an easier formula - `=round(AC2,0)` which will round as you're doing (and goes on to 4.5, 5.5 etc..)